# Autofac with multiple implementations of the same interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm using Autofac and would like to have multiple implementations of an interface. How can I configure Autofac so to resolve dependencies based on the current type?

More specifically, I have one interface and multiple implementations that should be chained together.

Let me explain (fictitious classes):

```
public interface IMessageHandler
{
    void Handle(Message message);
}

public class LoggingMessageHandler : IMessageHandler
{
    private IMessageHandler _messageHandler;

    public LoggingMessageHandler(IMessageHandler messageHandler)
    {
        _messageHandler = messageHandler;
    }

    public void Handle(Message message) 
    {
        // log something
        _messageHandler.Handle(message);
    }
}

public class DoSomethingMessageHandler : IMessageHandler
{
    private IMessageHandler _messageHandler;

    public DoSomethingMessageHandler (IMessageHandler messageHandler)
    {
        _messageHandler = messageHandler;
    }

    public void Handle(Message message) 
    {
        // do something
        _messageHandler.Handle(message);
    }
}
```

At the bottom of the chain might be an `IMessageHandler` that doesn't pass the message on to the next one.

If I want the following chain:

```
TopLevelClass -> LoggingMessageHandler -> DoSomethingMessageHandler -> FinalHandler
```

How can I tell Autofac to

- pass `LoggingMessageHandler` to `TopLevelClass` (to fulfill its dependency on `IMessageHandler`)
- pass `DoSomethingMessageHandler` to `LoggingMessageHandler` (to fulfill its dependency on `IMessageHandler`)
- pass `LoggingMessageHandler` to `FinalHandler` (to fulfill its dependency on `IMessageHandler`)

Is it even possible (I have read about the [implicit support for IEnumerable](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes#Example%3a_Implicit_IEnumerable_Support))? Or will I have to use an extra class in between (a factory or something)?

Comment: What you are describing is the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Your `LoggingMessageHandler` is a decorator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

4 options here: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html

Option 1: Redesign Your Interfaces

```
ILoggingMessageHandler , IDoSomethingMessageHandler
```

Option 2: Change the Registrations

```
builder.Register(ctx => new FinalHandler(ctx.Resolve<LoggingMessageHandler >()));
or
builder.Register(ctx => new FinalHandler(ctx.Resolve<IDoSomethingMessageHandler >()));
```

Option 3: Use Keyed Services

```
builder.RegisterType<FinalHandler>()
           .WithParameter(
             new ResolvedParameter(
               (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IMessageHandler),
               (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<ISender>("something")));
```

Option 4: Use Metadata

```
public class FinalHandler
{
  public FinalHandler([WithMetadata("sendBy", "something")] IMessageHandler messageHandler) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

[Autofac implicitly supports this by default](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b) via the use of [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1). Instead of having your depending class's constructor take in a single instance of `T`, you make it take in an instance of `IEnumerable<T>` that will contain every `T` registered:

```cs
public interface IMessageHandler
{
    void HandleMessage(Message m);
}

public class MessageProcessor
{
  private IEnumerable<IMessageHandler> _handlers;

  public MessageProcessor(IEnumerable<IMessageHandler> handlers)
  {
      _handlers = handlers;
  }

  public void ProcessMessage(Message m)
  {
      foreach (var handler in _handlers)
      {
          handler.HandleMessage(m);
      }
  }
}
```

Then in your registration, simply add multiple implementations of `T`:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<FirstHandler>().As<IMessageHandler>();
builder.RegisterType<SecondHandler>().As<IMessageHandler>();
builder.RegisterType<ThirdHandler>().As<IMessageHandler>();
builder.RegisterType<MessageProcessor>();
```

When `MessageProcessor` is instantiated, the `IEnumerable` it receives will contain three items as per the above registrations against `IMessageHandler`.

[You can read more about this on my blog.](http://www.whoiskevinrich.com/using-dependency-injection-for-implementation-enumeration)

Answer (score 13):

Autofac has [Decorators](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html) support.

Comment: Things have changed. While this answer will still work, I've changed the "correct" answer to @Jaider 's answer because it links to the official docs the provide 4 options.

Comment: I downvoted this because it simply has a link to a page (which is not guaranteed to be available in the future) with no substance in the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not too difficult. You can register concrete types as self and resolve it as you go along. Then your top level message handler (LoggingMessageHandler in your example) can be registered for the interface, which will be used by your TopLevelClass

Here's what you're looking at (assuming you have a default constructor for FinalHandler)

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<FinalHandler>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
builder.Register(c => new DoSomethingMessageHandler(c.Resolve<FinalHandler>())).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
builder.Register(c => new LoggingMessageHandler(c.Resolve<DoSomethingMessageHandler>())).As<IMessageHandler>().SingleInstance();
//now finally your top level class - this will automatically pick your LoggingMessageHandler since the others have been registered onto their concreteTypes only
builder.RegisterType<TopLevelClass>().As<ITopLevelClass>().InstancePerOwned();
```